# In webpack 5 what all plugins are inbuilt part from terser plugin.How to remove consoles from output bundle with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5

In webpack 5 what all plugins are in built apart from terser plugin.How to remove consoles from output bundle with webpack

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './styles/main.scss'

// replace console.* for disable log on production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  console.log = () => {}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Using this code i have removed my consoles in production.

All supported plugin list is given below in webpack 5:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/
But still not sure apart from terser plugin what all are in built plugins.